# How to partially change the colors of an image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

How can I change the RGB values for given indices in an image? This gives me a blank picture:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

target_image = Image.open("img.png")
target_image_array = np.array(target_image)
pixels = target_image_array.reshape(-1, 3)

skip_indices = np.arange(101_600, 254_000)

indices_to_grey_out = np.delete(pixels, skip_indices, 0)

pixels_greyed_out = pixels.copy()
pixels_greyed_out[indices_to_grey_out, [0, 1, 2]] = 0

pixels_greyed_out = pixels_greyed_out.reshape(target_image_array.shape)
modified_img = Image.fromarray(pixels_greyed_out)
modified_img.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do - please give a sample input image and corresponding output image. What do you mean by *"index"*? Do you mean at a certain position in the palette, or at a certain position in the image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell

I'll explain, it could be any image. I choose a color value, for example (25, 55, 145), i get all the indices in the flattened numpy array of the image where it matches the selected color (25, 55, 145). Then I'll darken the rest of the picture (every pixel except the colors (25, 55, 145), by meaning darken let's say the rgb value is (50, 50, 50).

The code in the post is the section I'm trying to darken the rest of the picture, that's why I chose `np.arange` but it's originally not a slice, there is a numpy array of thousands of indiscriminate indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with flattened and discontiguous indices at all, but going purely off your comments, I understand you want to affect some specific colours in an image so I'll try and demonstrate that.

Here is a radial gradient image that is `rgb(20, 50, 140)` at the centre and `rgb(40, 70, 160)` at the edge, so I happen to know there are 4,884 (non lineaarly adjacent, if that matters) pixels with value `rgb(25,55,145)`

[image]

Now, let's open it and make it into a Numpy array:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')
na = np.array(im)

# Make Boolean (True/False) mask of interesting pixels
mask = np.all(na==[25,55,145], axis=-1)

# Briefly save the mask so we can see what it selects
Image.fromarray(mask).save('DEBUG-mask.png')

# Let's also count the number of pixels selected by the mask
print(np.count_nonzero(mask))       # prints 4,884
```

[image]

Now we can use the mask to change the selected pixels. Let's make the masked pixels red in the original image:

```
na[mask] = [255,0,0]
Image.fromarray(na).save('DEBUG-1.png')
```

[image]

Now use the **inverse** of the mask to affect **unselected** pixels. Let's make them grey:

```
na[~mask] = [128,128,128]
Image.fromarray(na).save('DEBUG-2.png')
```

[image]

---

If you want to mask more than one colour, use can use logical operations to combine the masks together. So, let's say you wanted to additionally mask the colour rgb(28,58,148), you could add the following to the end of the code above:

```
# Mask for second colour
mask2 = np.all(na==[28,58,148], axis=-1)

# Combine the two masks into new, bigger mask
both = mask | mask2

# Make masked pixels yellow and display
na[both] = [255,255,0]
Image.fromarray(na).show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to mask a *range* of colours, I would suggest **OpenCV** `inRange()` which lets you set a lower and upper limit for R, G and B and then selects everything in-between.

```
import cv2

# Mask range 25>R>35, 55>G>65, 145<B<160
colRange = cv2.inRange(na,np.array([25,55,145]) ,np.array([35,65,160]))


# Make range of colours lime green
na[colRange>0] = [0,255,0]
```

[image]

---

If anyone is curious about how I made the radial gradient to start off with, I used **ImageMagick** in the Terminal and the following command:

```
magick -size 500x500 radial-gradient:"rgb(20, 50, 140)-rgb(40, 70, 160)" -depth 8 a.png
```

A simpler, clearer version might be:

```
magick -size 500x500 radial-gradient:lime-magenta -depth 8 a.png
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I want to ask another question to you. Can I mask for multiple color values, for example can I do something like that? `mask = np.all(na==[[25,55,145], [45,60,120], [78,15,190]], axis=-1)`

Comment: I have added some more material near the end of my answer to show a way of combining masks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change just one pixel, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

target_image = Image.open("/content/img.jpg")
target_image.putpixel((100, 200), (0, 0, 0))
print(target_image.getpixel((100, 200)))
plt.imshow(target_image)
```

if you want to change a slice of the image, better to change it to numpy first, then change values as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = Image.open("/content/img.jpg")
img = np.array(img)
img[100:200, 200:400] = 0
img = Image.fromarray(img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Alright, but how can I apply this for flattened array. there's no column info, there are only 3 columns for R, G and B. `img = img.reshape(-1, 3)`

Comment: It's better to handle images as 2D, not as 1D. To answer your question, it is the same, `img[start_ind:end_ind] = new_value`, but you will need to use a for loop to loop on each row as there will be discontinuity in indices

Comment: So you mean there's no way to do the way I'm trying to? Could you please take a look the post's code? I just updated but the output image looks same as the original image.

Comment: I am not saying that there is no way, what i am saying it will be more complex than simply modifying the image in 2d. Please add to the post your image shape, and indices you want to change, and I will update my answer to solve your case.

Comment: `target_image_array.shape` -> (559, 508, 3). `target_image_array.ndim` -> 3. `pixels.shape` -> (283972, 3). `pixels.ndim` -> 2.
I cannot include the indices because the indices are the pixels with same values, that's why I put `np.arange(101_600, 254_000)` as skip_indices, to demonstrate the indices are long array but discriminate unlike in my program. So it's not actually a slice, indices are long and indiscriminate numpy array.